# maven-ear-plugin ignores unpack option for modules

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, maven, ear

I have an Java EE 6 EAR-project with a couple of modules (jars & ejb). Assembling the EAR-file with the maven-ear-plugin, I basically want *all* artifacts to be packed / unexploded:

from the `pom.xml` of the parent file:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.5</version>
  <inherited>true</inherited>
  <configuration>
    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
    <version>5</version>
    <generateApplicationXml>true</generateApplicationXml>
    <defaultLibBundleDir>lib</defaultLibBundleDir>
    <archive>
      <manifestEntries>
        <app-version-info>${app-version-info}</app-version-info>
      </manifestEntries>
    </archive>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

from the `pom.xml` of the ear file:

```
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <configuration>
          <finalName>heap-poc</finalName>
          <modules>
            <jarModule>
              <groupId>com.example.heap</groupId>
              <artifactId>poc-common</artifactId>
              <bundleFileName>poc-common.jar</bundleFileName>
              <unpack>true</unpack>
              <includeInApplicationXml>true</includeInApplicationXml> 
            </jarModule>
            <jarModule>
              <groupId>com.example.heap</groupId>
              <artifactId>poc-persistence</artifactId>
              <bundleFileName>poc-persistence.jar</bundleFileName>
              <includeInApplicationXml>true</includeInApplicationXml> 
            </jarModule>
            <ejbModule>
              <groupId>com.example.heap</groupId>
              <artifactId>poc-business</artifactId>
              <unpack>false</unpack>
              <bundleFileName>poc-business.jar</bundleFileName>
            </ejbModule>
          </modules>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

The problem is that the [described unpack-switch](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ear-plugin/usage.html) seems to be completely ignored:

- poc-common.jar (unpack=true) is packed
- poc-persistence.jar (no unpack defined) is packed
- poc-business.jar (unpack=false) is exploded

I'm working with Eclipse Helios / m2eclipse, but from my understanding this shouldn't matter much for the problem.

Can someone push me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was wrong with my assumption that Eclipse is *not* responsible for the problem. As a matter of fact, maven from the command line does what it's supposed to do, it's "just" the rather complex integration of m2-eclipse and jboss-tools which seems to ignore the settings in question.

`mvn package` does exactly do what it's supposed to do :-)

A whole week of migrating an ant-based Java EE 5 project to maven and Java EE 6 taught me the hard way that Maven on JBoss in Eclipse is a whole lot different than Maven on the command line...